# What kind of mussels are these?

Tags: mussels

These are the mussels we bought:

[image][3](http://postimg.org/image/4vydrlb41/)

Comment: Do you have a picture of the outside of the shells? Those don't look at all like mussels to me, but maybe I'm not seeing the photo right.

Comment: Those are not mussels, they look like limpets to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those are `Arc Clams`. See this [link](http://www.clovegarden.com/ingred/seabival.html), they look the same.